# Installing a library from GitHub

Tags: shell, github, installation

I'm trying to install [FastScape](https://fastscape.org/fastscapelib-fortran/#install) and from what I've gathered all I need to do is run

```bash
git clone https://github.com/fastscape-lem/fastscapelib-fortran
cd fastscapelib-fortran
make install
```

I'm happy to keep all the libraries on their default settings. However, I keep getting this error message when I run `make install`:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.
```

And I don't understand where this is coming from, as my install file should be in the parent directory. Is there a step that I'm missing?

Comment: You still have to `cd` into the directory first, no?

Comment: yeah, i'm doing that. i forgot to add it to the code. i'll edit it now.

Comment: You also have to run the `cmake` line, right?

Comment: Yeah, there's no `Makefile` in that repo after checkout.

Comment: do you know why or how i should fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try running without any arguments to see what targets are available. :

```
make -p
```

If there is no install target listed, then you won't be able to use make install to install the library.

In this case, you can try manually copying the relevant files to the appropriate locations. The instructions for doing this should be provided in the FastScape documentation.